# Cross compile QtWebEngine for Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, qtwebengine, raspberry-pi4

I use qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0.tar.xz and gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-
linux-gnueabihf toolchain on an Ubuntu 18 to cross compile Qt and especially
QtWebEngine.

I use the following configure:

```
../qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0/configure \
  -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi4-v3d-g++ \
  -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- \
  -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot \
  -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi \
  -opensource -confirm-license -no-gbm \
  -skip qtscript -skip qtandroidextras -skip qtcanvas3d \
  -skip qtgamepad -skip qtmacextras -skip qtpurchasing \
  -skip qtwinextras -skip qtx11extras \
  -nomake tests -nomake examples -make libs \
  -pkg-config -no-use-gold-linker -v
```

If I include "-skip qtwebengine" in the configure command, all the compilation works well, but when I include qtwebengine the configuration fails with the following warning:

```
WARNING: Could not find all necessary libraries for qpa-xcb support in QtWebEngine.
WARNING: QtWebEngine will not be built.
```

After searching a while, I know the reason for this warning. QtWebEngine uses
pkg-config, to get the required libraries (e.g. xtst, xcomposite, ...) and take
the libraries on my host system instead of using the copied packages from the raspberry.

How can I configure it, to use the copied files from the raspberry sysroot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only libraries that seem to be missing are xtst, xcomposite, xi, etc.  Those are located on the Pi in /usr/share.  So your sysroot has to sync that folder as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I sync the /usr/share folder to my sysroot, the configure works well and QtWebEngine should be included. But if I then proceed with 'make', I got errors at the end and I found the following error in the log: "arm-
> linux-gnueabihf-g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)"